# Python Zip-File, wildcards

Tags: python

I was wondering how I could tell Python to extract only ".txt" files from a zip folder, using a wildcard. This code works fine for me:

```
extractor.extract("\websitefiles\test.hmtl")"
```

How can I use this same code to extract all .txt files in that current directory?  I was thinking something like this:

```
extractor.extract(".*.txt")
```

but it failed to work.. Any ideas???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just need python to extract .txt files in the current directory, that are no larger than 3 megabytes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import zipfile
from contextlib import closing

MiB = 2**20 # mebibyte

with closing(zipfile.ZipFile("example.zip")) as zfile:
    for info in zfile.infolist():
        if info.filename.endswith('.txt') and 0 < info.file_size <= 3*MiB:
            zfile.extract(info)
```

Answer (score 6):

First, you need the file names list, using `namelist()`.
Then, you can filter the "*.txt" files with `txtfiles = fnmatch.filter(fn_list,"*.txt")`
Now you can extract the files one by one:

```
extracts = [ extractor.extract(txt) for txt in txtfiles ]
```

Comment: @user715578: `fn_list == filename_list`  it is the list obtained with `namelist()`

Answer (score 2):

You would need to get the listing of all the files in the ZIP, then ask for each one, one at a time. Zipfile has the `namelist()` method to give you that list.

Comment: oh, how would I do it if i only wanted to extract .txt files no larger than 3 megabytes?

Comment: @user715578: Use the `file_size` member on the object returned by `ZipFile.getinfo(name)`.

Comment: ugh, I'm super lost. can anyone give me a sample code?? I just need python to extract .txt files in the current directory, that are no larger than 3 megabytes.

Comment: Here is some nice help for zipfile -- it should definitely be enough: http://effbot.org/librarybook/zipfile.htm

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `namelist()` to get the names of the files. Then select the txt files from the list and extract them one by one.